# Redis connection failure with Docker compose files

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm working with a docker-compose file from an open-source repo. Notably, it's missing the `version` and `services` keys, but it still works (up until now, I have not seen a compose file without these keys).

```
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - '6379'
app:
   build: .
   environment:
     - LOG_LEVEL='debug'
   links:
     - redis
```

`docker-compose up` starts everything up and the app is able to talk to redis via 127.0.0.1:6379.

However, when I add the `version` and `services` keys back in, connections to redis are refused:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379'
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL='debug'
    links:
      - redis
```

Which results in:

```
[Wed Jan 03 2018 20:51:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR { Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:896:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:919:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1073:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379 }
```

Why does adding `version: '3'` and `services:` lead to failure to connect?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the ports neither the links for services in the same network (compose file). You can use:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL='debug'
```

And then in your app code refer to redis just as 'redis:6379'. If you see the Dockerfile for the [redis image](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/99a06c057297421f9ea46934c342a2fc00644c4f/3.2/Dockerfile) you can see the port is already exposed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to expose the service to a specific host port, in Docker Compose version 3 you should use this syntax:

```
ports:
  - '6379:6379'
```

Check the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports):

> Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port
>   (a random host port will be chosen).

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem.  Mostly I am curious why removing  `version: '3'` and `services:` from the docker-compose file makes localhost work in the app container.  Perhaps it forces docker containers to see the network like the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me after having the same issue:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
    services:
      server:
        ...
        depends_on:
          - redis
      redis:
        image: redis
```

My redis config file:

```
const redis = require('redis');

const redisHost = 'redis';
const redisPort = '6379';
let client = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHost);

client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(`Redis connected to ${redisHost}:${redisPort}`);
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`Redis could not connect to ${redisHost}:${redisPort}: ${err}`);
});

module.exports = client;
```

Answer (score 0):

The port might be in use. Either kill the container using it or restarting docker will release the port.